Designing a Circuit to Connect and Disconnect a Load to a DC-DC Converter @3 MHz
I want to design a circuit to connect and disconnect a load to a DC-DC convertor:

There should be two switches, to connect the positive voltage and negative voltage at the same time to the load. The frequency of the On and Off is around 3 MHz. Could you please advise on which type of switch is best suited for this circuit: a MOSFET or a relay? Or using a multi-Channel Switches (IC)? In fact, I look for a minimum ON state resistor.
Requirements:
The time between each On and Off is 0.00333 m, “ON” resistor around 50 MΩ, leakage capacitance value: 12 pF, resistance value and “OFF” around 100 MΩ, regarding the voltage maximum it will 60 V and 8 A.

Why does both wires need to be switched? How much they are allowed to be not simultaneous, 1 picosecond or 1 millisecond or maybe 0.1 seconds? You are thinking a relay, but need to switch the relay on/off at 3 MHz? How much current is the load?

@Justme good question, do you mean If I connect one of them and connect and disconnect the second one? then I will now draw any current right? since the loop is open? "How much they are allowed to be not simultaneous, 1 picosecond or 1 millisecond or maybe 0.1 seconds?" literally at the time 0 s. the load is maximum 8A

@Andromeda Please explain in more detail why you need two switches. This is unusual.

@Jens it seems it is enough to use just one switch. based on the previous comments.

@Andromeda It is physically impossible to switch two things with infinitesimally small amount of time between the two switches. Relay contacts may switch and bounce and two transistors may have different turn-on and turn-off times.

@Justme then I will just use one switch, to open and close the loop.

GAN-FETs are close to a solution, but they will not provide the low leakage capacitance. How important is this requirement?

@Jens thanks for the answer and the solution, we do not have strict requirements on that.

I don't understand the requirements: the units are incommensurate and values do not match with the diagram. Please update the diagram to reflect what and how you are doing it. There exists no meaningful switching at 3MHz into megohm loads.

When switching at 3 MHz you can't use a relay but, to decide what might be suitable requires a stronger definition of what performance needs to be. For instance "ON" needs to be stated as a resistance value and "OFF" needs to be stated as (usually) a leakage capacitance value. Then you have to consider how quickly an off state becomes an on state.
You also need to state what voltages AND currents are being switched and, what device activates the switching (and its logic level).

the time between each On and Off is 0.00333m, "ON" resistor around 50 mOhm, leakage capacitance value:12 pF, resistance value and "OFF" around 100M ohm, regarding the voltage maximum it will 60V and 8A.

@Andromeda Please mention these requirements in the question.

@Andromeda 3.3 us period is only 300 kHz though? Typo?

My first idea for switching "medium" current at high frequency above 1 MHz was to use a GAN-FET, but the required low leakage current and low output capacitance changed the game a bit.
I compared the GAN-FET EPC2214 with the MOSFET IAUZ18N10S5L420ATMA1 and both will work at this frequency and power, but don't match all your requirements.
The GAN-FET has lower on resistance and gate charge, so I expect a much better switching efficiency using this kind of FET.
However the MOSFET has much lower output capacitance and leakage current and may be a better choice for your very special requirements.
Further improvements are possible if you cook a special cascode circuit, but this should be calculated if we know your exact application limits.

Cascode, with a buffered load voltage connected to the intermediate point?
